# Decoding declaration(a combination of array and function pointers) in C

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers

I've this piece of code:

```
(*I_dont_know ())[(int) ((*ptr))]

I_dont_know(), a function which takes void and returns a pointer.
ptr is an integer pointer.
```

As far as I can understand `[(int)((*ptr))]` ---> `ptr` is a function pointer which return an integer, rest I am not getting. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: What are `I_dont_know` and `ptr`?

Comment: The fragment does not compile.  That makes it impossible for anyone to help you decode it — we don't know what it is supposed to be.  You must provide an MCVE ([MCVE])!  (What is "`I_dont_know`", and `ptr`, and where's the semicolon, and is this at global scope or inside a function?)

Comment: if someone ask me what is meant by int a in c, I will simply reply a is variable of integer type. @Fei I will not cry as I don't know what is a.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. if someone as me what is (int)(*func) (int). I will simply reply as func is a pointer to function, which takes one integer as argument and return a integer instead of saying blah blah blah...

Comment: Well, since `(int)(*func)(int)` can compile — with the addition of a semicolon – I'd have no problem explaining that there's a redundant set of parentheses around the return type of a pointer to a function that takes a single `int` argument and returns an `int` value.  In Standard C (C90, C99, C11, C17), the code shown does not compile, even with a semicolon added at the end.  It certainly needs more context to show what is going on.  If `ptr` is declared as `int (*ptr)();`, then your analysis of `[(int)((*ptr))]` is incorrect — it is invalid to dereference a function pointer like that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , I was expecting this  answer as your first reply. This above post has done some good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is not a declaration, but it can be interpreted as an expression.

```
(*I_dont_know())[(int) ((*ptr))]
```

1. Call the function `I_dont_know` with no arguments. This function returns a pointer to something.
2. Dereference the returned pointer to get some object.
3. Meanwhile, dereference the value of `ptr` and cast it to an `int` value.
4. Then pass that `int` value as the argument for the `[]` (indexing) operator on that object returned in step 2. In C this could be another pointer or an array (arrays decay to pointers too). In C++ this could also be an object with the `[]` operator overloaded.
5. As this expression is not on the left-hand-side of an assignment then the value returned from the `[]` operator sub-expression (i.e. the element at the `*ptr`-index in the array) will be returned.

Assuming this is C, then the argument to the indexing operator should be cast as `size_t` and not `int`. If it's C++ then it should only be cast to `int` if the `[]` operator overload specifically accepts an `int` parameter operand.

Comment: C doesn't have overloaded operators; it must be a native array.  I think the function `I_dont_know()` must return a pointer to a pointer since you dereference it once on the LHS and a second time with the subscript.  But well done on the basic analysis.  I'll observe that you should not have had to infer as much as you have done.  I also observe that the question thinks it is a declaration, for reasons which are unclear.  As a declaration, it simply doesn't compile.  It requires a lot of context to compile as an expression, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the compliment. I forgot the OP was only asking about C and not C++. I've now amended my answer to be specific to C with a nod to C++.